# Sync calendars within outlook automatically (internally w/o Exchange)

Tags: calendar, outlook

I need a way that automatically (every so many minutes) Sync my main outlook calendar with another outlook calendar within the same outlook.

We do not have exchange. This is for my work. And need a free or super cheap solution. Have about 80 users.

Also I want this to stay internal, we currently sync with google and want to get out of the cloud with this.

Comment: Do you have a phone?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you need to develop an Outlook add-in or VBA macro for synchronizing Outlook calendars. See [Walkthrough: Creating Your First Application-Level Add-in for Outlook](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc668191.aspx) to get started quickly.